# Hover effect transition not working

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a hover image effect in my website. I attached the script in the below link. 
I can't able to set a hover image transition fade effect and 2s time delay.
Please help me.

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img class="myhoverimg" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="">
<div class="myhoveroverlay"></div></div>

<style>
.imagecontainer {
   position:relative;
   width:361px;
   height:181px; }
.myhoverimg{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
} 

.myhoveroverlay{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;   
   z-index:100;
}

.myhoveroverlay:hover{
        background:url(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg);

}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nhu2wmdg/

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/nhu2wmdg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use opacity attr to fade image...

```
.myhoveroverlay{
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;   
     z-index:100;
     opacity : 1;
}

.myhoveroverlay:hover{
    background:url(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images   /Windows%20Logo.jpg);
    opacity : 0.9;

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @Leo. Exactly what i was looking for.
[jsfiddle.net/nhu2wmdg/1](http://%20jsfiddle.net/nhu2wmdg/1)